What is the easiest way in Biopython to duplicate or "clone" a chain in a PDB file?
Like, say I have a PDB file with one chain (call it A for simplicity), and a symmetry matrix that sends it to a dimer partner and/or another molecule in an asymmetric unit. I want to now make one structure object with two independent copies of the chain, one the original chain (say "A") and the other a copy transformed by the matrix, but with all internal coordinates identical, and call the copy chain "B".
Transforming isn't the hard part--the trickier part is copying the chain (and have it still be part of the same structure object, so they can be saved together into one output file--which just copying it using deepcopy() seems like it wouldn't do, as well as quite possibly causing conflicts with IDs if the rename doesn't happen simultaneously), even if all atoms start in the exact same location as those in the original chain to be transformed later. It would seem that a simple one line copy-and-rename function should be included in the PDB package, as this would seem like a common use case. Something along the lines of:
model.add_chain(clone_chain('A','B'))
However, I haven't found one. In fact, aside from the StructureBuilder class, which builds things atom by atoms and needs lots of information that would need to be painstakingly extracted from the source chain, there are no functions I see for adding to molecules (as opposed to moving, renaming, or selecting atoms, residues, etc. that already exist).
As I said, I looked through the documentation for the PDB.Model, PDB.Chain, and PDB.StructureBuilder and didn't find anything like this.

have you tried looping over the original chain res by res and copying the res applying the symmetry and adding it to a new chain ID ?

OK figured out that class Bio.PDB.Entity.Entity , of which Chain is a subclass has a copy method / def copy(self): that uses shallow copy but detach the copied object from from its parent:
 def copy(self):
        """Copy entity recursively."""
        shallow = copy(self)

        shallow.child_list = []
        shallow.child_dict = {}
        shallow.xtra = copy(self.xtra)

        shallow.detach_parent()

        for child in self.child_list:
            shallow.add(child.copy())
        return shallow


Using this method its actually faster than my previous answer.
Here the code for the case above.
Input:
downloaded from RCSB PDB  pdb file 1jml.pdb ,here the monomer in PyMOL:

Using code below and symmetry matrix found at REMARK 350 of pdb file for second monomer of Biologically Assembly 2 :
REMARK 350   BIOMT1   2 -1.000000  0.000000  0.000000        0.00000            
REMARK 350   BIOMT2   2  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000        0.00000            
REMARK 350   BIOMT3   2  0.000000  0.000000 -1.000000       29.89850  

Code:
import Bio

from Bio.PDB import PDBParser

from Bio.PDB import PDBIO

import numpy as np


print('Biopython Versiom : ', Bio.__version__)

parser=PDBParser()
io = PDBIO()


rotmat = np.array([[ -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,        0.00000 ],
                   [ 0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,        0.00000  ],
                   [ 0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,       29.89850]])


structure = parser.get_structure('1JML', '1jml.pdb')


new_chain = structure[0]['A'].copy()

print(new_chain)

new_chain.id = 'Z'
            
print(new_chain, new_chain.parent)

structure[0].add(new_chain)

print(new_chain, new_chain.parent)

for resi in new_chain:
    
    # print(resi , '   : ')
    
    for atom in resi:
        
        # print(atom , atom.get_coord())
        
        
        ## see  ## see https://lists.open-bio.org/pipermail/biopython/2014-November/015475.html
        atom.set_coord(np.dot(rotmat[0:3,0:3],atom.get_coord()) + rotmat[:3,3])
        
        # print(atom , atom.get_coord())
    

io.set_structure(structure)
io.save("1jml_biopython_output_answer_2.pdb")

and here 1jml_biopython_output_answer_2.pdb vs in yellow dimer from 1jml.pdb

NOTE ABOUT DEEPCOPYING
CHAINS:
In your qustion you saind that you were deepcopying the relevant chain. Here a short scripts, using the same of above, pdb file 1jml.pdb as input that show the strange behaviour of deepcopying chains in Biopython due probably to the fact that each entity has a parent:
import Bio


from Bio.PDB import PDBParser

from Bio.PDB import PDBIO


from copy import deepcopy



print('Biopython Versiom : ', Bio.__version__)

parser=PDBParser()
io = PDBIO()


structure = parser.get_structure('1JML', '1jml.pdb')



new_chain = deepcopy(structure[0]['A'])

print("\nnew_chain = deepcopy(structure[0]['A']")
print('new_chain, new_chain.parent : ', new_chain, new_chain.parent)


print('\nchains in struture[0] : ')
for chain in structure[0]:
    
    print('chain ---> : ', chain)
    
io.set_structure(structure)
io.save("1jml_biopython_output_deepcopy_chains_1.pdb")


print("\n\nnew_chain.id = 'Z'")

new_chain.id = 'Z'
     

print('new_chain, new_chain.parent : ', new_chain, new_chain.parent)

print('\nchains in struture[0] : ')
for chain in structure[0]:
    
    print('chain ---> : ', chain)
    
io.set_structure(structure)
io.save("1jml_biopython_output_deepcopy_chains_2.pdb")


print('\n\nstructure[0].add(new_chain)')
structure[0].add(new_chain)

print('\nchains in struture[0] : ')
for chain in structure[0]:
    
    print('chain ---> : ', chain)


io.set_structure(structure)
io.save("1jml_biopython_output_deepcopy_chains_3.pdb")


Output:
Biopython Versiom :  1.83

new_chain = deepcopy(structure[0]['A']
new_chain, new_chain.parent :  <Chain id=A> <Model id=0>

chains in struture[0] : 
chain ---> :  <Chain id=A>


new_chain.id = 'Z'
new_chain, new_chain.parent :  <Chain id=Z> <Model id=0>

chains in struture[0] : 
chain ---> :  <Chain id=A>


structure[0].add(new_chain)

chains in struture[0] : 
chain ---> :  <Chain id=A>
chain ---> :  <Chain id=Z>

have a look at the 3 different output pdb files and see what happens in term of number of chains in the pdb files at each step

your question is not a lot clear , code and input are missing, you said you had problem with copying.
My attempt to recreate your problem and code to solve , below. Is not fast because I am looping over all residues and atoms to apply the symmetry matrix.
Input:
downloaded from RCSB PDB pdb file 1jml.pdb , here the monomer in PyMOL :

Using code below and symmetry matrix found at REMARK 350 of pdb file for second monomer of Biologically Assembly 2 :
REMARK 350   BIOMT1   2 -1.000000  0.000000  0.000000        0.00000            
REMARK 350   BIOMT2   2  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000        0.00000            
REMARK 350   BIOMT3   2  0.000000  0.000000 -1.000000       29.89850  

code :
import Bio


from Bio.PDB import PDBParser

from Bio.PDB import PDBIO

from Bio.PDB.Chain import Chain


from copy import deepcopy

import numpy as np


print('Biopython Versiom : ', Bio.__version__)

parser=PDBParser()
io = PDBIO()



rotmat = np.array([[ -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,        0.00000 ],
                   [ 0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,        0.00000  ],
                   [ 0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,       29.89850]])



structure = parser.get_structure('1JML', '1jml.pdb')


res_sym_marix = []

for model in structure:
    
    print(model)
    
    for chain in model:
        
        print(chain)
        
        
        for resi in chain:
            
            res_copy = deepcopy(resi)
            
            res_sym_marix.append(res_copy)
            
            
for resi in res_sym_marix:
    
    print(resi , '   : ')
    
    for atom in resi:
        
        print(atom , atom.get_coord())
        ## see https://lists.open-bio.org/pipermail/biopython/2014-November/015475.html
        atom.set_coord(np.dot(rotmat[0:3,0:3],atom.get_coord()) + rotmat[:3,3])
        
        print(atom , atom.get_coord())
    


new_chain = Chain("Z")

model.add(new_chain)

for res in res_sym_marix:
    new_chain.add(res)
    

io.set_structure(structure)
io.save("1jml_biopython_output.pdb")

I get as output a new pdb file 1jml_biopython_output.pdb with two identical chains A and Z.
Here in PyMOL  in red 1jml.pdb monomer vs 1jml_biopython_output.pdb

and here 1jml_biopython_output.pdb  vs in yellow dimer from 1jml.pdb


I ended up doing something similar to this, but deep copying the chain rather than each residue (though still applying the matrix per atom). Thanks. I was just hoping there was something more concise/"built in".

I found out that entity, chain is a subclass of entity has a copy method : https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/d398dfacaae80ee2e438577172ff01f1eb1b7f7f/Bio/PDB/Entity.py#L385chain that uses shallow copy but detach the copied bject from from its parent.  Think would be faster than your script if you used deepcopy

A shallow copy wouldn't have worked because each chain needed to have independent coordinates (see the original question). In other words, a shallow copy of a chain would contain references to the SAME residue and (indirectly) atom objects, and so transforming their coordinates would also move the original chain. The whole tree, all the way down to the atom "leaves", needs to be copied. In fact the PARENT (model) of the chain is the only thing that should NOT have been detached from the original--they needed to be two chains in the same model.

Not able to follow you. See my new answer it uses the copy method of the above : https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/d398dfacaae80ee2e438577172ff01f1eb1b7f7f/Bio/PDB/Entity.py#L385chain and apparently works in an eccellent way, let me know

Developers could change the  Entity,copy method in a way that accepts new chain name as argument and reattach the new chain to previous parent or assing a random one if that argument is not provided but that coulb be cumbersome because model chain rsidues are all Entity-es and copy works on all of them

I read the code for the "copy()" method and it DOES call copy() recursively on its children, i.e. it does a deep copy. That is why it works!

Detaching the first parent : shallow.detach_parent() and reattacching the copied child/drens to the copied  shallow.add(child.copy())

Can I have my brownie points now my second answer seems a reeasonable good one to me https://stackoverflow.com/a/78772393/9877065

In any case it does a copy not a deepcopy see here https://discuss.python.org/t/can-someone-please-explain-why-below-shallow-copy-code-eg-are-not-working-as-expected-note-in-the-case-of-shallow-copy-a-reference-of-an-object-is-copied-into-another-object-means-any-changes-made-to-a-copy-of-an-object-do-reflect-in-the-original-object/37759

and why not just:
struct = parser.get_structure("test",'/path/to/file')

chainA_as_B = struct[0]['A'].copy()
chainA_as_B.id = 'B'

struct[0].add(chainA_as_B)

